# Fb App is missing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps

I find that my app which is recently created(about 5hrs) is missing altogether(with no trace of any existence) and i did not get any notification (or email) from fb which we generally get if we forget to add pivacypolicy to FB App.

It was a sweepstake kind of app where user is asked to participate in the contest by submitting his emailid and phone number. and his participation is posted on his wall with a link to app(using feed post, and link is given out using link parameter in me/feed post).
we posted a status on our client's wall including the app link(even post is missing now).

May i know a place or link where i can find a reason for my app's restriction as i followed all the rules of fb to the best of my knowledge.

Here is the app id if it may help 675743852468369.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just check your email if any query send to you by facebook because it may be spamming that continously posting or something like that or you have to read facebook policy and updation.

Comment: I checked my inbox, but there is no mail from facebook or anything related.

Comment: then go to facebook support and ask them what is the reason they will response you in 24 to 48 hours

Comment: Can you please provide me the link? as i'm unable to find one,
thank you.